# OS X, app can't obtain root previliges when started from standard user

Tags: macos, installation, privilege

I'm trying to create an installer for OS X. To be able to write to directories owned by root (/Applications, /Library...) I'm using Authorization Services from the Security framework. The following code works fine with an admin user but fails with a standard user. Creation of the rights works without error message but the process still runs with lower privileges (no file is written at the mentioned position).

Of course I'm using the admin user's loginname/password for authentification.

```
    AuthorizationRef authRef;

    char rightName[] = "system.install.root.user";
    AuthorizationItem   kActionRight = { rightName, 0, 0, 0 };
    AuthorizationRights rights = {1, &kActionRight};
    AuthorizationFlags flags=kAuthorizationFlagExtendRights|kAuthorizationFlagInteractionAllowed;

    OSStatus err = AuthorizationCreate(&rights, 0, flags, &authRef);

    // [ write to a file in /Applications; doesn't work with standard users ]

    if (authRef != 0)
       AuthorizationFree(authRef, kAuthorizationFlagDestroyRights);
```

I know there are examples that use AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges(), but as this is deprecated in OS X 10.7 I'd rather avoid using it. Any idea what I'm doing wrong or what I need to do to obtain root privileges?

Thanks for any help,

Chris

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need use PackageMaker instead of writing your own installer. This save your time... And dependent of your requirement you can use HelperTools that will be automatically copy binaries to the /Library...

Comment: This is for an webinstaller, so PackageMaker isn't really an option. I'll have a look at HelperTools.